# What the idiom for a chain of promises?

Tags: promise, raku

How do I execute two promises, one after another?

For example, in JavaScript I can

```
var promise1 = new Promise();
var promise2 = new Promise();

// await returns a result2 from promise2
await promise1.then(() => promise2);
```

How do I do the same in Perl 6?

```
my $promise1 = Promise.new();
my $promise2 = Promise.new();

// Here I get only Promise2 object, not its result
await promise1.then({ $promise2 });
```

Must I just await a $promise2 like this?

```
await promise1.then({ await $promise2 });
```

Comment: This is wrong even in JavaScript. You should have been using `await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])` (and then get the second value from the result array if you're looking for that), as otherwise you might get unhandled rejections if `promise2` rejects before `promise1` settles. I'm certain there's a Perl equivalent to `Promise.all` as well

Comment: Your first code block is not a serial chain of promises.  Both are executing in parallel.

Comment: @Bergi, what if I need to use in the promise2 the result of the promise1?
Let's say the promise1 returns some token and then the promise2 uses it.

Usually I use something along the lines
`promise1.then(result1 => promise2)`

Promise.all executes all in parallel, not sequentally

Comment: @YuriyZhilovets That's ok, but then you wouldn't have written `var promise2 = new Promise(…);` outside of the `then` callback - you would construct it (using the token) inside the callback.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if they run in sequence or in parallel. Try `await $promise1, $promise2;` and ask a new question if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do two asynchronous operations one after the other, feeding the result of the first into the second, then it'd just be a case of doing two `await`s:

`my $result = await something-that-returns-a-Promise();
await something-else-returning-a-Promise-using($result);`

Or without the intermediate variable:

`await something-else-returning-a-Promise-using(await something-that-returns-a-Promise());`

No need for `.then` at all.

Comment: @jnthn Would it be possible / make sense if `Foo.then: &code`, when calling `&code`, automatically passed `$_` bound to `Foo`s result?

Comment: @raiph It passes the `Promise` that `.then` was called on as an argument; if `&code` is a simple block then it'll end up in `$_`. Thus you can do `$promise.then({ something-with(.result) })`, for example. The reason we pass in the `Promise`, not the result, is that the `Promise` may have been broken. Calling `.result` and not handling any exception from it will in turn break the `Promise` returned by `.then`, meaning unhandled errors are propagated down the chain.

Comment: @jnthn Perfect. Thanks. :)

Comment: @jnthn What if I want to combine a sequental chain of Promises (one Promise, getting the result and feeding it then into another) to the one single promise to return it e.g. as a result of some function?

Like then: `await get-token-and-then-get-result($url)`

The function `get-token-and-then-get-result` cannot do `await` itself, because it is in the responsibilty of the main program

Comment: @YuriyZhilovets You mean if you had some list of functions that each take an argument and return a `Promise`? Then I guess a reduce would be one way: `my @ops = -> $x { start { $x + 1 } }, -> $y { start $y * 2 }, -> $z { start $z - 3 };  my $p = (start { 4 }, |@ops).reduce: -> $prom, &op { $prom.then({ await(op(.result)) }) }; say await $p` or so.